# MySQL Insert queries not running

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just finished a script to import data from an XML file to MySQL, I have more than 280,000+ row, but after the import is done I only see 91,000 rows. After verifying if every query was running without any problem, I found the following one :

```
INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelId`, `hotelFileName`, `hotelName`, `rating`, `cityId`, `cityFileName`, `cityName`, `stateId`, `stateFileName`, `stateName`, `countryCode`, `countryFileName`, `countryName`, `imageId`, `Address`, `minRate`, `currencyCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `NumberOfReviews`, `ConsumerRating`, `PropertyType`, `ChainID`, `Facilities`) VALUES (1568054, 'Der_Obere_Wirt_zum_Queri', '\"Der Obere Wirt\" zum Queri', 3, 34633, 'Andechs', 'Andechs', 212, 'Bavaria', 'Bavaria', 'DE', 'Germany', 'Germany', 51498149, 'Georg Queri Ring 9', 92.1476, 'EUR', '48.009423000000', '11.214504000000', 16, 8.5, 0, 0, '1|3|5|8|22|27|45|49|53|56|64|66|67|139|202|209|213|256|')

Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hotels/public_html/insert.php on line 57
INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelId`, `hotelFileName`, `hotelName`, `rating`, `cityId`, `cityFileName`, `cityName`, `stateId`, `stateFileName`, `stateName`, `countryCode`, `countryFileName`, `countryName`, `imageId`, `Address`, `minRate`, `currencyCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `NumberOfReviews`, `ConsumerRating`, `PropertyType`, `ChainID`, `Facilities`) VALUES (1658359, 'Seclusions_of_Yallingup', '\"Seclusions\" of Yallingup', 4, 72257, 'Yallingup', 'Yallingup', 172, 'Western_Australia', 'Western Australia', 'AU', 'Australia', 'Australia', 53234107, '58 Zamia Grove', 238.7800, 'AUD', '-33.691192000000', '115.061938999999', 0, 0, 3, 0, '3|6|13|14|21|22|28|39|40|41|51|53|54|56|57|58|65|66|141|191|202|204|209|210|211|292|')

Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/hotels/public_html/insert.php on line 57
INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelId`, `hotelFileName`, `hotelName`, `rating`, `cityId`, `cityFileName`, `cityName`, `stateId`, `stateFileName`, `stateName`, `countryCode`, `countryFileName`, `countryName`, `imageId`, `Address`, `minRate`, `currencyCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `NumberOfReviews`, `ConsumerRating`, `PropertyType`, `ChainID`, `Facilities`) VALUES (1491947, '1_Melrose_Blvd', '#1 Melrose Blvd', 5, 964, 'Johannesburg', 'Johannesburg', NULL, '', '', 'ZA', 'South_Africa', 'South Africa', 46777171, '1 Melrose Boulevard Melrose Arch', , 'ZAR', '-26.135656000000', '28.067751000000', 0, 0, 9, 0, '6|7|9|11|12|15|17|18|21|32|34|39|41|42|50|51|56|58|60|140|173|202|293|296|')
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'ZAR', '-26.135656000000', '28.067751000000', 0, 0, 9, 0, '6|7|9|11|12|15|17|18' at line 1
```

This is my query code :

```
if($obj->stateFileName != "")
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelId`, `hotelFileName`, `hotelName`, `rating`, `cityId`, `cityFileName`, `cityName`, `stateId`, `stateFileName`, `stateName`, `countryCode`, `countryFileName`, `countryName`, `imageId`, `Address`, `minRate`, `currencyCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `NumberOfReviews`, `ConsumerRating`, `PropertyType`, `ChainID`, `Facilities`) VALUES ({$obj->hotelId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->hotelFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->hotelName)."', {$obj->rating}, {$obj->cityId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->cityFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->cityName)."', {$obj->stateId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->stateFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->stateName)."', '{$obj->countryCode}', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->countryFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->countryName)."', {$obj->imageId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->Address)."', {$obj->minRate}, '{$obj->currencyCode}', '{$obj->Latitude}', '{$obj->Longitude}', {$obj->NumberOfReviews}, {$obj->ConsumerRating}, {$obj->PropertyType}, {$obj->ChainID}, '{$obj->Facilities}')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    }
    else
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `hotels` (`hotelId`, `hotelFileName`, `hotelName`, `rating`, `cityId`, `cityFileName`, `cityName`, `stateId`, `stateFileName`, `stateName`, `countryCode`, `countryFileName`, `countryName`, `imageId`, `Address`, `minRate`, `currencyCode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `NumberOfReviews`, `ConsumerRating`, `PropertyType`, `ChainID`, `Facilities`) VALUES ({$obj->hotelId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->hotelFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->hotelName)."', {$obj->rating}, {$obj->cityId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->cityFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->cityName)."', NULL, '', '', '{$obj->countryCode}', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->countryFileName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->countryName)."', {$obj->imageId}, '".mysql_real_escape_string($obj->Address)."', {$obj->minRate}, '{$obj->currencyCode}', '{$obj->Latitude}', '{$obj->Longitude}', {$obj->NumberOfReviews}, {$obj->ConsumerRating}, {$obj->PropertyType}, {$obj->ChainID}, '{$obj->Facilities}')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `You have an error in your SQL syntax` error, you can just look at the actually query where it tells you to spot the problem. Searching for `ZAR` I found this:

```
..., '1 Melrose Boulevard Melrose Arch', , 'ZAR', '-26.135656000000', ...
```

As you can see, `, ,` is not valid syntax, it is missing an element. Looking at your code it seems like it is missing `{$obj->minRate}`. This field is empty for some records (or at least for the one record you posted). To fix this, you can try replacing that with:

```
is_null($obj->minRate) ? 'NULL' : $obj->minRate
```

For the `mysql_free_result` warning, you haven't shown the code where that method is called, so it's hard to say what that's about.

Answer (score 3):

The insert syntax is invalid, it contains two commas with no value: `'1 Melrose Boulevard Melrose Arch', , 'ZAR',`

Try changing it to:
'1 Melrose Boulevard Melrose Arch', `NULL`, 'ZAR',

Also, this probably means that whatever converted the XML to SQL insert statements has a bug. But you haven't provided us any of that code so it wouldn't be possible to help you fix it here.